# Run function after inline confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wan to run all jQuery codes after **inline** confirmation, Is this possible?

something like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="return confirm('are you sure ?')" > test link </a>
```

I want this code run after inline confirmation above:

```
$('body').on('click','a',function() {
    alert('clicked!');
});
```

It's important to me that confirmation take place inline, not in jQuery `on click`.

Comment: Can you change the in-line code?

Comment: Better, can you move the first function out of your HTML and use an event handler instead?

Comment: yep, or overwrite it after its been created with jquery. Javascript inside HTML is the mother of many problems

Comment: As I said before I can not move inline code to event handler. Because HTML elements creates in php files and I can translate confirmation messages.but in js files i cannot use php codes

Answer (score 0):

here is the code which will work for you.

```
<a href="#">  test link </a>
```

and jquery code is below which will help you.

```
$('body').on('click','a',function() {
    var msg = confirm('are you sure ?');
    if (msg){
        alert('ok is clicked');
    }else{
       alert("cancel is click")
    }
});
```

Comment: or you can add class to anchor if you have more than one anchor tag in your page and can call click event on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
function onConfirm()
{
    if (!confirm('are you sure ?')) 
       alert('clicked cancel');
    else
        alert('clicked confirmed');

};

 <a href="#"  onclick='onConfirm();'> test link </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return confirmMessage('are you sure ?');"> test link </a>

function confirmMessage(msg) {
    if (confirm(msg)) {
        alert('confirmed');
    } else {
        alert('failed');
    }
}
```

or

```
<a href="#" onclick="whenConfirm(confirm('are you sure ?')).done(confirmed).fail(canceled);"> test link </a>

function whenConfirm(is_confirmed) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    is_confirmed ? d.resolve() : d.reject();
    return d.promise();
}

function confirmed() {
    alert('confirmed');
}

function canceled() {
    alert('canceled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using inline click handlers. I would also set a class or id on the anchor you intend to put this handling on. Otherwise, you would be binding this confirm on each anchor element in the document.

```
<a href="#whatever" class="confirm-me">Confirm</a>

$(document).on('click.confirm','a.confirm-me',function() { 
    if (confirm('Are you sure ?')){
        alert('ok is clicked');
        // Returns true;
    }else{
       alert("cancel is click");
        // Returns false;
    }
});
```